# How to send array in params using Alamofire multipart from data using swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3, multipartform-data, alamofireimage

I am using `Alamofire` for uploading an image and a file to the server. But I am having an issue to send an array in parameters with the image. But when I send an array in params it converts the array in `JSON` string. But I want to send an array in params, not in `JSON` string. I have searched a lot but did not get any solution. Here is the code below.

```
let params = ["id":"101","arrayParam":["1232","12344","14325"]]

    let url = www.khxjjhdfsj.com/hsdgs
            let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                /* "Authorization": "your_access_token",  in case you need authorization header */
                "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
            ]
            Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
                for (key, value) in params
                {
                     multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
                }
                if let data = imageData
                {
                    multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "file", fileName: fileName, mimeType: "image/png")
                }
                if let data = pdfData
                {
                    multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "file", fileName: fileName, mimeType:"application/pdf")
                }
            }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: url, method: .post, headers: headers) { (result) in
                switch result{
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        print("Succesfully uploaded")
                        if let err = response.error
                        {
                            onError?(err)

                            return
                        }



                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    onError?(error)
                   }
            }
```

Comment: you have to send "arrayParam" as parameter? or the whole params ?

Comment: @chandra1234   i will send "arrayParam" as parameter

Comment: Can you try with this line . "arrayParam[\(key)]" instead of only adding key

Comment: @chandra1234 -can you explain this with the help of code?

Comment: Did you found the solution? @Deevakarverma

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, may be you will get

```
var dict = Data()
    let params:[String:Any] = ["id":"101","arrayParam":["1232","12344","14325"]]

for (key, value) in params {
    if key == "arrayParam" {
    if let str:[String] = value as? [String]{
          // to convert [String] to data
          dict = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: str, count: str.count))
         // to retrive [String] from data
        let arr2 = dict.withUnsafeBytes {
            Array(UnsafeBufferPointer<String>(start: $0, count: dict.count/MemoryLayout<String>.stride))
        }
        print(arr2)
    }
    }
    multipartFormData.append(dict, withName: key)
    }
```

Comment: @Deevakarverma i updated my answer pls check ,in this way you will append only array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't saw any accepted answer so sharing my solution. It's tested and working.

```
let arrayObj = value as !Array<Any>
for i in 0..< arrayObj.count {
    let value = arrayObj[i] as !String
    let keyObj = key + "[" + String(i) + "]"
    form.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: keyObj)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 let params = [
        "key":value,
        "key1": key2] as [String : Any]



    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30000

    manager.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params)
        .responseJSON {


            response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
               stopActivityIndicator()
                print(response)
                if let result = response.result.value {
                    let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                    print(JSON)
                    let ResponseSuccess = JSON.object(forKey: "response")!
                    self.displayAlert(Message: ResponseSuccess as! String, myView:self)


                }


            case .failure( _):

                if let result = response.result.value {
                    stopActivityIndicator()
                    let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                    print(JSON)
                    let ResponseFail = JSON.object(forKey: "response")!
                    self.displayAlert(Message: ResponseFail as! String, myView:self)
                }
            }


    }
```